# Selenium webdriver not finding elements

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrap atlanta's property info map. (https://gis.atlantaga.gov/propinfo/)
I'm using selenium to try and access the searchInput class in the html doc
I have tried using the 114.0.5735.90 and the 120.0.6099.62 drivers and got the same error

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time
import os


def openingDriver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #options.add_argument('headless')
    options.binary_location = '{}\{}'.format(os.getcwd(),'chromedriver.exe')
    webDriver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    return webDriver

webDriver = openingDriver()
webDriver.get('https://gis.atlantaga.gov/propinfo/')

time.sleep(9)

container = webDriver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'searchInput')
container.send_keys("586 COOPER ST SW")
container.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(15)

pane = webDriver.find_element(By.ID, 'cp_left')
soup = bs(pane.text, "html.parser")
```

and this is the error log:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51566/devtools/browser/55df9e1b-4248-4bab-9346-b4963fe07b7b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\name\Documents\archive.py", line 24, in <module>
    container = webDriver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'searchInput')
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\env\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 739, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\env\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 345, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\env\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".searchInput"}
  (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.62); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x006D6E73+174291]
        (No symbol) [0x00600AC1]
        (No symbol) [0x00316FF6]
        (No symbol) [0x00349876]
        (No symbol) [0x00349C2C]
        (No symbol) [0x0037BD42]
        (No symbol) [0x00367054]
        (No symbol) [0x0037A104]
        (No symbol) [0x00366DA6]
        (No symbol) [0x00341034]
        (No symbol) [0x00341F8D]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x007749CC+820268]
        sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x00834EBE+652494]
        sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x008348D9+650985]
        sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x0082962C+605244]
        sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x0083586B+654971]
        (No symbol) [0x0060FEBC]
        (No symbol) [0x00608428]
        (No symbol) [0x0060854D]
        (No symbol) [0x005F5858]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x77257BA9+25]
        RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77A8BD2B+107]
        RtlClearBits [0x77A8BCAF+191]
```

Any ideas?

I tried using different drivers and using the direct Xpaths

Answer (score 1):

First, there are 2 'class' is 'searchInput': a 'div' and a 'input'. Obviously, you should find 'input'.

[image]

Second, iframe exists.
[image]

so right way is:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(ec.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'ifrSafe')))
container = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@class="searchInput"]')))
```

Plus, find elements and use waiting as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the element that you are looking for wasn't rendered on the page yet. You could try to wait a couple of seconds in order to run the rest of the code.

Example of code that you could add after `time.sleep(9)` or replace with:

```
...
currentWait = WebDriverWait(webDriver, 21)
container = currentWait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'searchInput')))
container.send_keys("586 COOPER ST SW")
container.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

pane = currentWait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'cp_left')))
soup = bs(pane.get_attribute('innerHTML'), "html.parser")
...
```

In this code the web driver will wait 21 seconds before trying to look for the class name.

I hope this post helps you a little bit.